# Swift - Convert string to double without scientific notation(exponents)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string which is in exponents. For example my string is

`"-4.17182640083098e-31"`

I have an array of values like this. I want to use this to draw chart.
The graph accepts double values only to plot it. When I convert it to double using `Double(str)` and using it in graph is not working because the graph library not accepting exponents.

So I converted this to decimal value the result is

`-0.0000000000000000000000000000011803449813502`

So I again converted this decimal to double it gives the same `-4.17182640083098e-31` with exponents notation.
So can't use this is graph. So please suggest a way to convert this to double without the exponents/scientific notations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no exponents in Double. They are only in the string represention. Its a way we write really small or big values. If th chart is wrong, its not because of exponents. Please show us the problem with the chart.

Comment: I get the double value is -0.00000000000000000000000000000041718264008309799. There is no exponents notation in double value, exponents notation appears only when you print it. Maybe your graph lib doesn't accept the long decimals.

Comment: @Sulthan chart not even appearing. It is stuck at setting data to chart.

Comment: @YunCHEN but it works is the libraries android version. May be 
I can report an issue in that library.